# Comparing time stored in a String

Tags: java, swing, datetime

I have a time in string format like "02:00" in 24 hours and I want to check it between two other time,such that "07:00"and "15:oo" .How can I check for this, as the time is in string format ?

I use the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
String s2=simpDate.format(date);
JLabel1.setText(s2);
```

now I want to check if that String s2 is inbetween "7:00" and "15:00" then set the value to another JLabel named JLabel2 as: "First Shift"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: I want to do comparision of Systemtime with the String..How can do it

Answer (score 2):

You use a `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the `String` to a `Date`. Then you can compare the dates together.

Read more about [SimpleDateFormat here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: I am using the SimpleDateFormat. I have got the Current System time..now I want to compaire this with another time how can I do this..Can I explain more

Comment: You can get the milliseconds of a Date with the method `getTime()` then you can just use greate/smaller operators to find out which one is bigger.

Comment: I use the following code:                              SimpleDateFormat simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
String s2=simpDate.format(date);JLabel1.setText(s1); now I want to check if that String s2 is inbetween "7:00" and "15:00" then set the value to another JLabel named JLabel2 as:"First Shift"

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to parse your strings to `Date` object instances. You can use the `DateFormat` derived classes to do so (i.e. `SimpleDateFormat`).

Then, you can do comparisons using the millisecond-representation of both dates (obtained via `getTime()`) or just compare them using either `after(Date date)` or `before(Date date)`.

If you need more complex operations you should use the `Calendar` class.

Besides, if your project works a lot with dates I'd suggest using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

**EDIT (in response to comment):**

Using `Calendar` class it would be this way. First you need a calendar instance for your 7:00 date:

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.DATE, 12);       // The day of month you are working with
cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);       // The month of the year
cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);     // The year
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7); // Hour in 24-hours fashion
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);      // self-explanatory
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Date shiftStart = cal1.getTime();
```

Then do the same for the end of the shift:

```
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set( ... );       // Repeat almost every field from previous snippet
cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15); // Hour in 24-hours fashion

Date shiftEnd = cal2.getTime();
```

Then, you just need to check the date you want to compare is between those:

```
Date myDate = ...   // the date you want to compare
boolean checkShift = myDate.after(shiftStart) && myDate.before(shiftEnd);
```

Anyway, as I already said, if you will work with dates a lot in you project I would use Joda Time, as it will ease a lot date handling.

Comment: I use the following code: SimpleDateFormat simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm"); String s2=simpDate.format(date);JLabel1.setText(s2); now I want to check if that String s2 is inbetween "7:00" and "15:00" then set the value to another JLabel named JLabel2 as:"First Shift"

Comment: @Jayashri instead of copy-pasting that comment under every answer, consider updating your question.

Comment: I updated my answer, and agree with Robin, you should update your question